# mapview not showing the annotated point

Tags: ios, ios5, mkannotation, mapkit

I am trying to plot a point in the mapview. 
I have created two files 
1. A file which extends nsobject, and,
2. A file which extends views.
Here is source code for both the files:

```
#import "gpMapViewAnnotations.h"

@implementation gpMapViewAnnotations
@synthesize title, coordinate;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d {

    title = ttl;
    coordinate = c2d;
    return self;
}
```

this is the code for interface file.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface gpMapViewAnnotations : NSObject <MKAnnotation>{

    NSString *title;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d;


@end
```

@end

Now this is the source code for view files:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/Mapkit.h>
#import "ASIHTTPRequestDelegate.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "gpMapViewAnnotations.h"

@interface gpViewController : UIViewController
< ASIHTTPRequestDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate>
{
     MKMapView *gpMapView;


    gpMapViewAnnotations *gpAnnotations;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *gpMapView;

@end
```

And here is the implementation file:

```
#import "gpViewController.h"
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "Parser.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "TFHpple.h"
#import "TouchXML.h"
#import "gpMapViewAnnotations.h"


@interface gpViewController ()

@end

@implementation gpViewController
@synthesize gpMapView;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    // Set some coordinates for our position (Buckingham Palace!)
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = (double) 51.501468;
    location.longitude = (double) -0.141596;

    // Add the annotation to our map view
    gpMapViewAnnotations *newAnnotation = [[gpMapViewAnnotations alloc] initWithTitle:@"Buckingham Palace" andCoordinate:location];
    [gpMapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://v1.syndication.nhschoices.nhs.uk/organisations/gppractices/location.xml?apikey=YAHUGHET&range=50&northing=174900&easting=517900&name=richmond"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setDelegate:self];

    [request startAsynchronous];
    [gpMapView setDelegate:self];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setGpMapView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
     NSLog(@"view did load");
    NSLog(@"request finished");
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
//   NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
    // Use when fetching binary data

    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];

    //  we will put parsed data in an a array
    NSMutableArray *res = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //  using local resource file
   // NSString *XMLPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.xml"];
  //  NSData *XMLData   = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:responseString];
    CXMLDocument *doc = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];

    NSArray *nodes = NULL;
    //  searching for piglet nodes
    nodes = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//*" error:nil];
    NSLog(@"coming here 1");
    for (CXMLElement *node in nodes) {
        //NSLog(@"coming here 2");

      //  NSMutableArray *item = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        //create list object to store the title and latitude and longitude.
        List *gpList = [[List alloc]init];

        if([[node localName] isEqualToString:@"entry"]){
            NSArray *entryTagNodes = [node children];

            //iterate on entry nodes
            for(CXMLElement *entryTagNode in entryTagNodes){
                //check if the tagname is content
                if([[entryTagNode localName] isEqualToString:@"content"]){
                        //iterat on content tag childs
                    NSArray *contentTagNodes = [entryTagNode children];
                    // NSLog(@"tag: %d",[contentTagNodes count]);
                    for(CXMLElement *innerContentNode in contentTagNodes){

                        NSArray *organisationTagNodes = [innerContentNode children];
                        for(CXMLElement *orgTagNode in organisationTagNodes){
                           // NSLog(@"%@",[orgTagNode localName]);

                                //check for tag name is equal to name
                            if([[orgTagNode localName] isEqualToString:@"name"]){
                                gpList.title = [orgTagNode stringValue];

                            }else if([[orgTagNode localName] isEqualToString:@"geographicCoordinates"]){
                                NSArray *geoCordTags = [orgTagNode children];

                                for(CXMLElement *geoCordTag in geoCordTags){
                                    if([[geoCordTag localName] isEqualToString:@"latitude"]){
                                        gpList.latitude = [geoCordTag stringValue];

                                    }else if([[geoCordTag localName] isEqualToString:@"longitude"]){
                                        gpList.longitude = [geoCordTag stringValue];
                                    }

                                }
                               NSLog(@"latitude nad longitude %@ %@",gpList.latitude,gpList.longitude);

                            }
                        }
                    }


                }

            }
            [res addObject:gpList];

        }

        //  and here it is - attributeForName! Simple as that.
      //  [item setObject:[[node valueForKey:@"id"] stringValue] forKey:@"id"];  // <------ this magical arrow is pointing to the area of interest



    }

    //  and we print our results
  //  NSLog(@"%@", res);
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [res objectEnumerator];
    id obj;
    while(obj = [enumerator nextObject]){

            NSLog(@"title %@",[obj title]);

    }

    /*
    TFHpple *doc = [TFHpple hppleWithData:responseData isXML:YES];
    NSArray *elements = [doc searchWithXPathQuery:@"/"];

    NSLog(@"%d",[elements objectAtIndex:0]);
   */
    /*
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseData];
    Parser *parser = [[Parser alloc] initParser];

    [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];
    BOOL worked = [xmlParser parse];
    if(worked){
        NSLog(@"parsing is happening ");

    }else{
        NSLog(@"parsing is not happening %@",[app.listArray count]);
    }*/


}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    id <MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate], 1500, 1500);
    [mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [mv selectAnnotation:mp animated:YES];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}

@end
```

I dont have a clue as where i am doing wrong in plotting a simple point. i still need to put multiple points using the array which i have created reading the xml file. but even a simple point is not getting plotted now.
Is there anything which I am doing wrong over here please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see your `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` delegate method. That's where you can add the view to go along with annotations. Something like this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if( annotation == mapView.userLocation ) return nil;

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView;
    annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"AnnotationIdentifier"];
    if( annotationView == nil ){
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"AnnotationIdentifier"];
    }

    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: can you please explain the code and the parts which i need to change for accroding to my code?

Comment: You'll have to add this method to your mapview delegate.

Comment: I am sorry, i am a bit new to this..could u please explain which delegate? I have added the protocol mkmapviewDelegate to the interface.

Comment: Add it to your `gpMapViewAnnotations.m` file, which is the `MKMapviewDelegate`.

Comment: I did it..and its showing me `Use of undeclared identifier 'delegate'`

Comment: Have you set the delegate properly?

Comment: I have set `[gpmapView setDelegate:self];` in viewdidload